# C# string to number, TryParse returns true when Parse fails

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, number-formatting, tryparse

I have a column in my database (SQL Server) storing averages as **varchar**.

Values are not always valid numbers, it can be something like : `0`, `12`, `5.5`, `.4`, `4.0`, `6.`, `5.21428571428571428571428571428571428571`, `X`, `fail`, or simply empty text.

When assigning variable with **linq**, I want to display :

- `success` if average is valid number and >= 4
- `failed` if average is valid number and < 4
- the raw text if average is not a valid number

The code :

```
myresults = myDataContext.myDbFunction()
double note;
from a in myresults
select new MainReportModel()
{
    Id = a.id,
    Lastname = a.nom,
    Firstname = a.prenom,
    Average = a.moyenne,
    Result = double.TryParse(a.moyenne.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out note) ? (double.Parse(a.moyenne.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < 4 ? "failed" : "success") : a.moyenne
}
```

But **Parse** fails.

When replacing `double.Parse(a.moyenne.Trim()` with any hardcoded value (for example `double.Parse("3.3"`) it works fine.

So it seems one of the values of `a.moyenne.Trim()` is causing **Parse** to fail.

How can it fail if **TryParse** returned **true**?

**Edit** : Here is the error message :

```
Could not translate expression 'value(MyProjectWeb.Models.MyProjectDataContext).myDbFunction().Select(a => new MainReportModel() {Id = a.id, Lastname = a.nom, Firstname = a.prenom, Average = a.moyenne, Result = IIF(TryParse(a.moyenne.Trim(), Number, Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Globalization.CultureInfo])), Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Double]))), IIF((Parse(a.moyenne.Trim(), Number, Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]))) < 4), Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.String])), "success"), ((a.moyenne) + "</span>"))})' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing what the value is?

Comment: I would not expect this to happen. Could you paste the input string that throws the exception?

Comment: What about iterating through your data and trying it one by one until you run into the value causing the problem?

Comment: Also, instead parsing it twice, couldn't you do something like this? `double.TryParse(a.moyenne.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out note) ? note < 4 ? "fail" : "success" : a.moyenne;`

Comment: @GrawCube Debugging does not allow me to see the records one by one. I already tried using the `note` variable but it is always `0`. I will update my post with the error message when i'm able to reompile my code.

Comment: Generally, I have found that it's not a good idea to use framework level functions within an EF query like this because often EF attempts to run those functions *at* the SQL server where they are not valid.  And the error message you posted in your edit seems to back that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform TryParse on the Sql server, but if you are not doing further selection criteria, then you can try pulling the data from Sql as it is and then parsing on the client.

eg

```
myresults = myDataContext.myDbFunction()
double note;

var list =(from a in myresults
select new 
{
   a.id,
   a.nom,
   a.prenom,
   a.moyenne,
}).ToList();


var finalResults = (from a in list 

select new MainReportModel()
{
   Id = a.id,
   Lastname = a.nom,
   Firstname = a.prenom,
   Average = a.moyenne,
   Result = double.TryParse(a.moyenne.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number,    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out note) ? (double.Parse(a.moyenne.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < 4 ? "failed" : "success") : a.moyenne
}
```

Comment: Indeed! Just adding `ToList()` did the trick : `myresults = myDataContext.myDbFunction().ToList()`. However I'm not sure to understand why it worked using an hardcoded value.

Comment: If you have a hard-coded value, then it doesn't depend on your Sql Table and hence is performed on the client side, ie  your select statement will just be `select id, nom, prenom, moyenne from ...`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use TryParse at second one also?

```
Result = double.TryParse(a.moyenne.Trim(), NumberStyles. Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out note) ? (double.TryParse(a.moyenne.Trim(), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < 4 ? "failed" : "success") : a.moyenne
```

Try that.

Comment: `double.TryParse` returns a boolean, you cannot compare it to the number that way.